# Adding Left Swipe Gesture to MKMapView Without Interfering With Panning

Tags: ios, swift, mkmapview, uigesturerecognizer

I have 2 views:

- Map View
- Friends List

Rather than use a Tab Bar Controller (which I initially implemented) I would like the user to be able to swipe between the 2 views - Swipe left to see the 'Friends List' and swipe right to go back to the MapView.

The issue I have is that the mapview obviously allows the user to pan the map so  if they initially start to pan left the left swipe gesture is invoked and the friends list comes into view.

Can any one advise if there is a way to implement a left swipe gesture on a mapview without interfering with the panning of the mapview.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Screen edge pan gesture to show your friend list. When Screen edge pan starts you can also disable gesture recognizer of mapview if you want.

Comment: Thanks rv7284 for your response. The screen edge gesture was something I considered but then realised it wouldn't work too well for the users as the app is geared towards cyclists, in an ideal world they would need to be able to swipe anywhere on the screen to access the friends list without having to be overly accurate.